# Is this a v3.1.0 problem or did I break something? Some things are disabled in the settings

Tags: cycles-render-engine, camera, gpu

This is my first project in 3.1 so i just found this out. Back in 3.0 this wasnt a problem so im wondering if something changed between updates or if i did something wrong that made the render region setting to be unusable as well as the render device being locked up in the GPU with no option to change it.

Technically i can check the boxes but because its greyed out, nothing happens

[image: As you can see, the render region is greyed out and the render device is as well]

Comment: Probably a 3.1 bug, especially if you're on Windows.  Edit preferences and go to the Systems tab. Check the Cycles Render devices.  You may have to toggle between None and Cuda or Optix to get Blender to recognize your GPU again.

Comment: @MartyFouts changing the settings in the render devices worked, thanks. Both options got active again